# Flutter Quill Delta format display into widget?

Tags: flutter, quill, rich-text-editor

I am currently using Quill as my WYSIWYG Editor which uses delta format to save data.
I have successfully extracted the delta format to JSON but how should I display it on the screen as a readable format?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Quill to display the JSON to.

```
class ExampleView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuillController _controller = QuillController(
        document: Document.fromJson(YOUR_JSON),
        selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0));
    return QuillEditor.basic(
      controller: _controller,
      readOnly: true, // true for view only mode
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).